# How to make code more simple (if/else)

Tags: c#

How to make this code more simple?

```
if (PlayersLevel > 1)
    button4.Visible = true;        
else
    button4.Visible = false;

if (PlayersLevel > 2)
    button5.Visible = true;
else
    button5.Visible = false;
```

**Okay, okay, enough, I already knew =) Thanks**

Comment: FYI there is http://codereview.stackexchange.com/

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Just set the value to the result of the comparison:

```
button4.Visible = PlayersLevel > 1;
button5.Visible = PlayersLevel > 2;
```

Answer (score 3):

```
button4.Visible = (PlayersLevel > 1);
button5.Visible = (PlayersLevel > 2);
```

Answer (score 3):

You dont need the If statements, you'll get `True` / `False` with following

```
button4.Visible = PlayersLevel > 1;        
button5.Visible = PlayersLevel > 2;
```

Answer (score 2):

A little Linq encapsulation to make for intentional code can't hurt. Drop in this extension method

```
public static void VisibleWhen( this Button button , bool visibilityState )
{
  button.Visible = visibilityState ;
}
```

Then you can say:

```
button4.VisibleWhen( PlayersLevel > 1 ) ;
button4.VisibleWhen( PlayersLevel > 2 ) ;
```

Comment: Is this a troll? You're concerned that assigning a boolean value to a standard boolean property might be unclear, so you want replace it with an extension method nobody's ever heard of, with no verb in the name?

Comment: I don't see any LinQ here.

Comment: He probably thinks extension methods are LINQ. They're certainly very much associated with it. In fact, I seem to recall they may have been added in large part to make LINQ possible.

Answer (score 1):

Bool results you can use.

```
button4.Visible = PlayersLevel > 1;        
button5.Visible = PlayersLevel > 2;
```

Answer (score 0):

```
button4.Visible = PlayersLevel > 1;
button5.Visible = PlayersLevel > 2
```

?

Answer (score 0):

Another way of going about it:

```
button4.visible = PlayersLevel > 1 ? true : false;
button5.visible = PlayersLevel > 2 ? true : false;
```

Comment: The ternary is unecssary, but a good option to be aware of.

Comment: I prefer using an explicit ternary expression in cases like this: it makes the intent quite clear.

Comment: @NicholasCarey Right, anybody who doesn't know what a boolean expression is will understand a ternary with ease.

Comment: @webdad3 Going out of your way to confuse new programmers is poor practice. But now I'm feeding the troll, and I try not to do that. Cheers.